# Keyboard-configuration: /usr/local/bin/setupcon: 900: /usr/local/bin/setupcon: /usr/local/bin/ckbcomp: not found

Tags: package-management, upgrade

After trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, the background is no longer fixed in position but moves around with the mouse as if I have zoomed in.

Running `sudo dpkg --configure keyboard-configuration` gives the following results:

```
keyboard-configuration (1.178ubuntu2.7) is set up...  
/usr/local/bin/setupcon: 900: /usr/local/bin/setupcon: /usr/local/bin/ckbcomp: not found   
dpkg: Error editing the keyboard-configuration (--configure): package:
 subprocess installed keyboard-configuration package post-installation script returned error exit statis 1
Errors occurred when editing:
 keyboard-configuration
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives the same results.
Does anyone know the reason for this error

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Leads to the very same error message. (Except the very last line is missing E:Sub...)

Comment: Let's look at the first error - that's where it seems to go wrong. What exactly is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure keyboard-configuration`? Please edit your question and paste this output in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried out:

```
sudo apt-get remove keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, after a reboot I could not login. After entering the password a short black screen and than asking again for the password. Entering the save mode and repairing the broken packages (dpkg) fixed everything and the problem is solved. Most likely some other command for the reboot would have been a good idea - but it worked.

Credit goes to Pascalc answering the question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202671/circular-dependency-in-ubuntu-release-upgrade